# how to send POST data with jquery ajax to PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to send POST request with jquery AJAX to PHP function
but it don't give any respond.

**JQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ListProduk.php/SelectData',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include 'database.php';

function SelectData(){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM MsProduk";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $arr[] = $row;
  }
  return json_encode($arr);
}
?>
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: `url: 'ListProduk.php/SelectData',` that doesn't make sense. Look at your developer console, use php's error reporting and check for errors on the query. You'll see what's (not) happening here.

Comment: `url: 'ListProduk.php/SelectData',` that translates to having a folder called `ListProduk.php` with a sub-folder called `SelectData`. The `SelectData()` method's usage is unknown. You've a variable scope issue here.

Comment: You can maybe send the function name through `GET` variable and just call it from within your php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When not using url rewriting (google mod_rewrite and pretty URL's), your parameters typically are going to be passed as a normal HTTP `GET` request. Here is an example of how your URL structure might look:

```
url: 'ListProduk.php?action=SelectData'
```

And then, in your PHP, you might handle it based on the action that is requested (Note: The `action` parameter is not something specific to web development, it's just an arbitrary name I assigned. It could be `foo=SelectData` as well)

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'SelectData') {
   // Run the code for selecting data
}
```

Finally, you wouldn't want to "return" the JSON data. You need to output it with the correct headers. It would look something like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```