# Can't reach PHP code from a JQuery POST Call (Error Undefined Index)

Tags: php, jquery, post

I am trying to pass data from a JS script to a PHP file.
I am using JQuery post as follows:

```
   const Url2 = 'MainPage2.php?action=updatePurchaseToDB';
   const data = {
       action: "updatePurchaseToDB",
       name: "test name"
   }


   //takes 3 arg, url, data to send, call back function, data in callback holds the page reqeusted in data

   $.post(Url2,data, function(data, status){
       console.log(`status is ${status} data : ${data}`);
       alert("PHP Retrned form server:  Status " + status + " Data: " + data);
   });

    }
```

This appears to execute correctly as the status is returned as successful.
The PHP code I am looking to reach :

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'updatePurchaseToDB'){


      echo "<script>$(`#purchaseButton`).html('Test- received data');</script>";
    }
```

The following error is thrown:
*Undefined Index: action*

Not sure why as the *action* is declared in the URL and data parameters.

If I try same with a Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'MainPage2.php?action=updatePurchaseToDB',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data)
        {
          console.log(data);
        }

      });
```

Again I get a successful response form the server and same error. 
I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947022/how-to-send-post-data-with-jquery-ajax-to-php-function) but I must be reading it incorrectly.

I understand there are allot of answers with a similar question but I was having difficulty finding same for my situation.

Input appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Contents of `$_POST` is data lines after HTTP headers.

But your `action=updatePurchaseToDB` is part of the request url.  You should access it thru `$_GET["updatePurchaseToDB"]`.

And one question about

```
echo "<script>$(`#purchaseButton`).html('Test- received data');</script>";
```

Isn't it should be

```
echo "<script>$('#purchaseButton').html('Test- received data');</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, even if the parameter is in the url or as a data parameter, you are calling as a GET, so the Post is index unavailable.

In the second case you are doing a post, but the parameter 'updatePurchaseToDB' is a GET parameter, you aren't sending any data to PHP file. again, the index will be unavailable.

Try it:

```
const data = {
action: "updatePurchaseToDB",
    name: "test name"
}
$.ajax({
    url: 'MainPage2.php?action=updatePurchaseToDB',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks but didn't make any difference. Same 'index action 'error. The idea is to send an array to PHP  for processing contents into a database. To check I have reached the PHP code successfully I want the PHP to print to a DOM element by echoing a script call, am I missing something here?

Comment: I just tested it here and it worked perfectly without any errors.

Comment: The PHP executed and outputs the echo? In my set up the JS script is a external file to the PHP, I wonder what’s different then your set up

Comment: Can I see your PHP ?

Comment: is on the pastebin in the end, after < /html>

Comment: You’ve lost me, i don’t see a closing html tag, also noted you called the MainPage2.php as the full url in the POST call, in my set up the PHP is just MainPage2.php

Comment: Out of interest what are you running your code in, a browser or IDE of some sort?

Comment: I just copied and pasted the url, but, if you remove the query string, it will work too.

Comment: I am using google chrome, xampp on localhost and sublime text to edit the files :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212738/discussion-between-josimar-and-dancingbush).